# How do I create a file tree in Qt? (setRootIndex() didn't do anything)

Tags: qt

I have a QTreeView and I tried calling `setRootIndex()` and then `update()`, but nothing is displayed. Here's the code I was using, but to no avail,

```
QDirModel model;
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setAnimated(true);
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setSortingEnabled(true);
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setModel(&model);
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setRootIndex(model.index(QString("C:/")));
sc_me->ui->treeView_2->update();
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with `QDirModel` and the way it was called. It needs to be a pointer in setRootIndex for reasons I do not know. I also changed it to a QFileSystem Model, like this:

```
QFileSystemModel* model = new QFileSystemModel();
    sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setAnimated(true);
    sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setSortingEnabled(true);
    sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setModel(model);
    sc_me->ui->treeView_2->setRootIndex(model->index(QString("C:/")));
    sc_me->ui->treeView_2->update();
```

Comment: In your original version a stack-allocated model will be deleted on scope exit. The reason treeView does not crash is that it monitors when the model is deleted and clears its state.